# Can't get 'get_the_title' to work in a function

Tags: php, wordpress

I've used this in other functions, but it doesn't seem to work in this particular one...

```
  <?php
      $page = get_the_title();
      $blogusers = get_users('orderby=display_name');
      foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
        $cpt_count = wpse31443_author_has_custom_post_type( $user->ID, $page );

        if (!empty($cpt_count)) {
          echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '' . $cpt_count1 . '</li>';
        }
      }
    ?>
```

If I change  `$page = get_the_title();` to  `$page = 'title';`then it works, so it's something with get_the_title(); but I'm not sure what because it has worked in other functions.

Comment: Can you echo out the value of `$page`, to see if there's anything actually in there?

Comment: What page is this being used in? Is it in the loop? Should you be seeing the title for a post/page? If it's not in the loop, then you have to pass the post ID - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reason why "get_the_title()" wont work is if it is not in "the loop". Make sure that you call the function from within the loop only. If called from elsewhere, you will need to pass the page/post id to the function.

You'll get more information here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: This wasn't actually the case for me, but you got me going in the right direction. It was a stupid mistake, because the post type starts with a lower case letter and the page starts with an uppercase letter. THANKS!

Comment: In case anyone wonders, this did the trick...
`  
 $page = get_the_title();
 $page = strtolower($page); `

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
<?php
  global $post;

  $page = $post->post_title;
  $blogusers = get_users('orderby=display_name');
  foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    $cpt_count = wpse31443_author_has_custom_post_type( $user->ID, $page );

    if (!empty($cpt_count)) {
      echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '' . $cpt_count1 . '</li>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. It actually was another issue altogether but this would have helped if it was outside the loop. Thanks!